# Xcode 4 and git issue

Tags: iphone, git, xcode4

The base project is managed in git of Xcode 4. Then, I have another project that will use also the same base code but different UI only. How I can copy the base project or do I need to add another working local copy?

Answer (score 0):

If the two programs are closely related, you could simply stay within the project, but creating a new branch for that variation (See [XCode4 SCM guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)):
You would stay in the same local copy, but you would update your local working tree, switching from one branch to another.

[image: branches in XCode4]

That may be simpler that trying to use [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) in this case (unless you have many projects reusing the same base code).